# UniWebView prefab not showing up

Tags: c#, android, uniwebview

I'm trying to set up an Android application using unity.
Little problem : UniWebView is not working.
My phone is Android 7.0.

I've tried running the demo on my phone : It's not working neither.

There is no code to show.

There are no error messages. The background just stays blue on the demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, Unity didn't install the "plugin" folder